# Cordova Tools for Visual Studio - PushNotification has no method init

Tags: azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-cordova

I'm trying to create a Cordova app in Visual Studio that will receive push notifications from Azure Mobile Services. I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/

I installed it by opening the config -> Plugins -> Custom and putting in the above GitHub address. It installs fine, but I must be missing something, because this code doesn't work:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
                'AZURE_MOBILE_URL',
                'MY_API_KEY');
// Create a new PushNotification and start registration with the PNS.
var pushNotification = PushNotification.init({
    "android": { "senderID": MY_SEND£ER_ID}
});
```

Running in the Goolgle Android Emulator, it says that init is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if the plug-in didn't install correctly. I've often deleted my whole project and re got the source code then add the plug-in again

Also sometimes getting a local copy of the plug-in helps